# Popup orientation is not correct. Its 90 degrees rotated

Tags: silverlight, popup, windows-phone-7

Hi
I have created a popup using Popup class in silverlight. I wrote a class of type UserControl  and I added this usercontrol to the popup by using Child method of Popup class.

Following is the XAML code of my UserControl class

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.PopupWindowContent"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"            
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Cursor="Hand">

    <Grid Height="355" Name="grid1" Width="527.5">
        <Image Height="355" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="527" Source="/MyProject;component/dialog_bg.png" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
        <Image Height="194" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,87,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="502.5" Source="/MyProject;component/dialog_box_1.png" />
        <Image Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25.25,35.25,0,0" Name="image3" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49.75" Source="/MyProject;component/dialog_logo.png" />
        <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153.25,38.75,0,0" Name="popupHeading" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26" />
    <Button Content="Submit" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130.75,265.75,0,0" Name="buttonOne" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132.25" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF06EF06" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button BorderThickness="1" Content="Cancel" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,265.75,142,0" Name="buttonTwo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132.25">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEF0606" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    <TextBox Height="162.75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,108.25,0,0" Name="popupBody" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480.5" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" />
</Grid>
```

I set this PopupWindowContent to my popup using following code in my xaml file

```
        Popup popUnWin = new Popup();
        popUnWin.Child = new PopupWindowContent();
        popUnWin.IsOpen = true;
```

Problem is that when I execute this code, popup orientation is according to portrait but my app is landscape. So popup looks 90 degrees rotated. 
Can anyone please tell me how can i fix it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you put the popup into the xaml code of the page, then the orientation is done properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `SupportedOrientation` on every page of your app or just the first?  I think there's a wierd thing that if you set it on your first page, some things will respect it, but others (like the popup) look at the supported orientations of the active page?

Comment: Yes i have added SupportedOrientations="Landscape" on the current page on which the popup being displayed. I tried rotating the whole popup. Its works but since I have a textbox on the popup, when i try to enter something in this popup, the keyboard appears in portrait view :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some suggestions of adding the popup to the visual tree. I tried adding it to my xaml and it still didn't rotate, but you might want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rotate the popup but place a border inside the popup and load the content in the border.

I got it to work like this:

```
//In .xaml
<Popup x:Name="myPopup">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="480" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="popupBorder"/>
    </Grid>
</Popup>

//In .xaml.cs
popupBorder.Child = new MyPopupPage(); //MyPopupPage is the "Windows Phone Landscape Page"
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```